# Steps to creating a Google Analytics-like data visualization system

Tags: php, jquery, data-visualization

I wish to create a web dashboard for my team (day-to-day visualization). I am looking for some insight as to how to proceed (perhaps steps, best technologies, etc). I am confortable with jQuery, PHP, HTML/CSS, but I lack in terms of mySQL, which is probably needed in this case.

So, here are the requirements:

1/ I need to create an input interface where I would manually enter the data for the day (which could possibly be replaced eventually with API calls to the services, but I am making it manual for now)

2/ A database to capture the data

3/ A dashboard to display the info
    3.1/ Various Chart types,
    3.2/ *** A DATE RANGE SELECTION TOOL
    3.3/ The data itself, values only in a table

So as you can see, it is really Google Analytics-ish.

Can you help me figuring what technologies I should use, best practices, good resources such as tutorials, techniques, and examples.

Thanks in advance!

Jonas

Comment: what is your expertise?? or your company employees expertise area??

Comment: We are gathering information on our own Social Platforms (numbers like followers, likes, etc) and publication hits, views, etc. As for our expertise, we are a marketing firm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you migh consider using HighCharts for this purpose. HighCharts can talk easily to any JSON interface, have a look here for examples: http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/how-to-use#live-charts

A sample Database call might work like this:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("hostname", "user", "password");
mysql_select_db("mydb");
$result = mysql_query("select * from mytable");
$obj = mysql_fetch_object($result);
mysql_free_result($result);

echo json_decode($obj);

?>
```

This would return a valid JSON from the server, to which you can point your highcharts and build the charts. Good Luck!

Comment: Oh, and did i mentioned HighCharts also allows you to export into PDF, PNG, JPG etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can use embeddable chart widgets and update them automatically without SQL queries or database -- simply using Dropbox and CSV files (or FTP). Here is step-by-step guide how to do this: http://blog.explainum.com/2011/03/how-to-load-data-to-explainum-from.html

Example of a web-page with several widgets: http://blog.explainum.com/p/sample-widgets.html

The widgets have date range selection, zooming and comments linked to date ranges. Only line charts are available.